# Conjecture: $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{256}{163x}\sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor x\rceil} |\sin n|=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, conjectures

I conjecture:  $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{256}{163x}\sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor x\rceil} |\sin n|=1$$

Is this provable? If this is false, then can I have a function $f$ such that:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)\sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor x\rceil} |\sin n|=1$$

Comment: What is $\lfloor x \rceil$?

Comment: Round(x) @David

Comment: The nearest integer to $x$? This won't make a difference to your question but what do you do with a half-integer?

Comment: The entire limit would oscillate a little to much for my comfort if the upper were to just be $x$

Comment: Your conjecture is more likely to work with $\pi/2$ than with $256/163$.

Comment: Hmmm. You are probably right. I am not sure if I should make an edit. @David

Comment: It's your question, but I think the conjecture is correct in that case.

Comment: @David Yes, I will leave it. It seems to be much more interesting in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will show that
$$\lim_{N \to +\infty} \frac{\pi}{2N} \sum_{n = 1}^N | \sin n| = 1.$$
Then your statement (with $256/163$ replaced by $\pi/2$) will follow since $\lfloor x \rceil /x \to 1$ as $x \to + \infty$.

Let $f(x)$ be any left-continuous step function on $[0,\pi]$ satisfying $f(x) \leq \sin x$. Say $0 = x_0 < x_1 < \dots < x_r = \pi$ and $f(x) = a_k$ on $[x_{k-1},x_k)$. Then
$$\sum_{n = 1}^N | \sin n| \geq \sum_{n=1}^N f(n \operatorname{mod} \pi) = \sum_{k=1}^r a_k S_{k,N}$$
where $S_{k,N}$ is the number of elements in the set $\{n \operatorname{mod} \pi\ \mid n = 1, \dots N\} \cap [x_{k-1},x_k).$ Since the sequence $n \operatorname{mod} \pi$ is [equidistributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence#Examples) in $[0,\pi]$, we have $S_{k,N}/N \to (x_k - x_{k-1})/\pi$ as $N \to +\infty$. Thus
$$\frac{\pi}{2N} \sum_{n = 1}^N | \sin n| \geq \frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{k=1}^r a_k \frac{S_{k,N}}{N} \xrightarrow[N \to +\infty]{} \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^r a_k (x_k - x_{k-1}) = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\pi} f(x) \, dx.$$
Therefore
$$\liminf_{N \to +\infty} \frac{\pi}{2N} \sum_{n = 1}^N | \sin n| \geq \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\pi} f(x) \, dx.$$
The supremum of the right-hand side as $f$ is allowed to vary among left-continuous step functions $\leq \sin x$ is $\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin x \, dx = 1$, hence
$$\liminf_{N \to +\infty} \frac{\pi}{2N} \sum_{n = 1}^N | \sin n| \geq 1.$$

Arguing similarly with step functions $g(x) \geq \sin x$, we find that
$$\limsup_{N \to +\infty} \frac{\pi}{2N} \sum_{n = 1}^N | \sin n| \leq 1.$$

Combining the two inequalities, we have proved that
$$\lim_{N \to +\infty} \frac{\pi}{2N} \sum_{n = 1}^N | \sin n| = 1.$$